# vim syntax: match all lines with a given pattern that follow a line with a different pattern

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

I'm writing a Syntax file for [Robot Framework](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html).  I want to create a color scheme for the `[Documentation]` tag, such that the text following the tag, and all subsequent lines beginning with `...` until the next line that does not begin with `...` are matched.  So for example:

```
1    Test Case 1
2        [Documentation]  This
3        ...    Is
4        ...    Documentation
5        [Setup]    Run Keywords    Keyword1
6        ...    AND        Keyword2
```

I want to match lines 2-4, but not 1, 5, or 6.  I'm not sure if this is possible, and if so, I have no idea where to start.

Comment: I'm not sure the `robotframework` tag applies -- this question seems strictly about how to create a vim color scheme. The fact that it's robot framework seems beside the point.

Comment: fair point.  removed it.

Comment: That's a good question.  You might want to ask it on [vi.se].